# Add subtitles into the JW player

Tags: jwplayer

I'm playing a movie online, I was wondering if is it possible to add subtitles into JW player ?

Answer (score 0):

For JW Player 6.x you have built in subtitles functionality:
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28845/adding-video-captions/

For JW Player 5.x you have captions plugin
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw5/31151/captions-plugin